# How to fix the error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, eclipse, apache, maven, dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Serializer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The error is occurring right where the first `<dependency>` is located for OpenCsv. I tried using re-formatters online, but all my efforts were unsuccessful.

Comment: your pom is wrong. look at https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview

Comment: Everything must be inside the `<project>` (so before the `</project>`), you can only have one 'root' element in an XML file, for maven that is `<project>`